# How to solve the newline problem with code?

Tags: python-3.x, newline

I'm trying to write a data (list) into a csv file but it gets adding empty line after every row.

```
from csv import  writer

list = [["Name", "Age", "Sex"], ["John", 30, "Male"]]
with open("writer.csv", "w") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = writer(csv_file)
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        csv_reader.writerow(list[i])
```

[image: output]

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure the code you posted is the code you actually ran?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, it deoends if you use Linux, Mac OS, or Windows. As these three OS use different end of line markers: LF/CR/CRLF

Comment: @ThunderPheonix But unless the text editor is horribly broken, that wouldn't result in newlines being doubled.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I have just edited my answer with more explanation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from csv import  writer

list = [["Name", "Age", "Sex"], ["John", 30, "Male"]]
with open("writer.csv", "w", newline="") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = writer(csv_file)
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        csv_reader.writerow(list[i])
```

I just added `newline = ""` in `open` function

Based on the documentation:

> When writing output to the stream, if newline is None, any `'\n'`
>   characters written are translated to the system default line
>   separator, `os.linesep`. If newline is `''` or `'\n'`, no translation takes
>   place. If newline is any of the other legal values, any `'\n'`
>   characters written are translated to the given string.

If you use Windows, `os.linesep` is equal to `'\r\n'`, so if you specify `newline = None` (which is by default), any `'\n'` is converted to `'\r\n'`, that's why you have an additioonal newline.

Comment: There's a non sequitur here: "any `'\n'` is converted to `'\r\n'`, that's why you have an additioonal [sic] newline." Converting `\n` to `\r\n` is normal and does not generally result in additional newlines.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica But if you have a text edtor that interprets `'\r'` and `'\n'` bith as newlines, you will have blank line.

Comment: Do you know of any real text editor with that **bug**?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica not really, just saying!